# Re-using a stream in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In using Java streams in a project, I attempted to re-use a stream as such.

I start with a collection of objects, then do some filtering.

```
Collection<MyClass> collection = /* form the collection */;
Stream<MyClass> myStream = collection.stream().filter(/* some filter */);
```

I then want to re-use this same stream multiple times. For instance, first I want to just get the first item from the stream, as such.

```
MyClass first = myStream.findFirst().get();
```

Then I do some other stuff, and later I want to use the filtered `myStream` again to perform an operation on each object in the stream.

```
myStream.forEach(/* do stuff */);
```

However, when I try to do this, I get this error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
```

I can solve the issue by doing one of the following:

- Create a new stream from the original collection and filter it again
- Collect the stream into a filtered collection, then create a stream on that

So I guess there are a few questions I have based on my findings.

1. If you cannot re-use streams, then when would it ever be useful to return an instance of a stream for later use?
2. Can streams be cloned so that they can be re-used without causing an `IllegalStateException`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If you cannot re-use streams, then when would it ever be useful to return an instance of a stream for later use?

If you have a method that returns a stream and you need that stream to do two things, just call the method two times and get two different streams.

> Can streams be cloned so that they can be re-used without causing an IllegalStateException?

Lambda expressions make it easy to set up a `Supplier<Stream>` so you can avoid rebuilding it.  It might be an overkill if all you do is one `.filter`, but for more complex stream setups that are too local to warrant a method, this is a good option:

```
Supplier<Stream<MyClass>> sup = () -> collection.stream().....;  /

first = sup.get().findFirst().get(); // do one thing
sup.get().forEach(...);  // do another thing
```